# Nginx location: CGI and Nagios

Tags: nginx

Nginx should redirect any CGI requests to "/usr/share/nagios/sbin" under the following conditions:

```
    location ~ \.cgi$ {
    AND
    location /nagios {
```

Each condition works fine on its own. Requests to "newco.com/nagios" go to the right place, and requests to "whatever.com/*.cgi" go to the same place.

But how can I combine them, such that only "newco.com/nagios/*.cgi" end up in the "/usr/share/nagios/sbin" directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this one work?

```
location ~ ^/nagios/.+\.cgi$ {
```